# Why does "button" not work?

Tags: python

```
btnTotal = Button(RightMidFrame, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Total", bd =6, width=15, command = Product) 
btnTotal(row=10,column=0) 
lblExit = Button(RightMidFrame, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Exit", bd = 6, width=15, command = iExit) 
lblExit.grid(row=10,column=1) lblReset = Button(RightMidFrame, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Reset", bd = 6, width=15, command = Reset) 
lblReset.grid(row=10,column=2)
```

The below is the error:

```
btnTotal(row=10,column=0)

TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable
```

Comment: Did you mean `btnTotal.grid(row=10,column=0)`?

Comment: The error is that button doesn't work

Comment: Thankyou, actually it works